# a question related least common multiple

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, self-learning, least-common-multiple

$ 1, 3, x, 15, y, 75$

These above six numbers are divisors of a number $z$, and these numbers are ordered from the least one to the highest one.

How to find numbers $x, y, z$?

Comment: 'multipliers' makes no sense, and neither would 'multiples', so I guess you mean 'divisors'?

Comment: yes i can say as a "divisor"  @joriki

Comment: can you answer this question? @joriki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $15$ divides $z$, $5$ also divides $z$. Since $75$ divides $z$, $25$ also divides $z$. Thus $x=5$ and $y=25$. That yields the list of all divisors of $75$, so $z=75$.